# For which real values of $p$ is the following series convergent

Tags: analysis

> For which real values of $p$ is the following series convergent?
>   $$\sum_{n\mathop=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n^2\log n)\cdot(n^{\frac1n}-1)^p}$$

Please give some ideas, thanks.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: A basic idea: to do something, *try something.* Rewriting $n^{1/n}$ as $e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln n}$ and seeing what the quantity $(n^{1/n} - 11)^p$ "behaves like" (asymptotically) would be a good start.

Comment: It's hard to solve it by $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$, so I'm wondering other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p\leq 0$, as $n^{1/n}\geq 1$ the series converges, easily *(why?)*. Assume now $p> 0$.

From the Taylor expansion (two terms) of $e^u$ when $u\to 0$ applied to $\frac{\ln n}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$,
$$n^{1/n} - 1 = e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln n} - 1 = 1+ \frac{\ln n}{n} + o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right) - 1 = \frac{\ln n}{n} + o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right).$$
From there,
$$(n^{1/n} - 1)^p = \left(\frac{\ln n}{n} + o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)\right)^p
=
\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^p \left(1 + o\left(1\right)\right)^p 
= \left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^p + o\left(\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^p\right)$$
and the general term of your series is asymptotically equivalent to something much simpler:
$$\frac{1}{n^2 \ln n(n^{1/n} - 1)^p}
\sim_{n\to\infty }  
\frac{1}{n^2 \ln n\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^p}
=\frac{1}{n^{2-p} \left(\ln n\right)^{1+p}}
$$
Now, conclude by theorems of comparison.

**Spoiler:**

> The series with term as in the RHS is a Bertrand series; it converges iff $(2-p>1)$ or ($2-p=1$ and $1+p > 1$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use equivalents:
$$\Bigl(n^{\tfrac1n}-1\Bigr)^p=\Bigl(\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln n}n}-1\Bigr)^p\sim_\infty\Bigl(\frac{\ln n}n\Bigr)^p,$$
so the general term is equivalent to the general term of a *Bertrand's series*:
$$\frac1{n^{2-p}\bigl(\ln n)^{1+p}}.$$

Comment: I think the exponent of the logarithm should be $1+p$, not $2+p$.

Comment: @Clement C.: Oh! yes. I wrote is from memory,and didn't check. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: My pleasure! ${}{}$